# Setup Ejabbered on a VPS

Tags: installation, xmpp, ejabberd, vps

I am trying to setup ejabberd on debian vps and you can see there is something running on 5222 and 5269 port but there is nothing on 5280 and you cannot access admin to configure the server

I have tried following tutorials...

https://chat.openai.com/share/fcfaf285-82eb-4e4d-872a-69e0bd9aecec
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ejabberd-xmpp-server-on-ubuntu
and https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/installation/#administration-account

If someone could help me out, it would be of great help to me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, depending on where do you download ejabberd, it may have custom configurations.

When compiled from the official source code packages, the default configuration file setups port numbers 5222, 5223, 5269, 5443, 5280, 3478, and 1883.

The ecs container image has a slightly modified configuration file.

Surely the Debian package, and other packagers, may adapt the configuration file to their systems.

You should check your ejabberd.yml configuration file to check what exact port numbers are configured, and for what purpose.